# Reflection / Class -> NamedClass

Tags: java, reflection

I'd like to know how to be able to use a Class as per normal after loading it using a CustomClassLoader.

Main.java

```
...
Class <?> clazz = customClassLoader.get("MyClass");
MyClass myClass = _____________________; //fill in the blank, please
```

How do i make clazz into MyClass, so that I do not have to use all the troublesome things like getConstructor(), getMethod() etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because having `MyClass` in the source text...

```
MyClass myClass = ...;
```

...requires that `MyClass` be available at compilation-time.

The usual solution here is to use an *interface* which is available at compilation-time, and have `MyClass` implement the interface.

```
Class <?> clazz = customClassLoader.get("MyClass");
TheInterface myClass = (TheInterface)clazz.newInstance();
myClass.someInterfaceMethod();
```